# How to find oldobjectid when Uploading/pushing a file to Azure Devops Repo using Pushes Create Api with Python

Tags: python, git, azure-devops, python-requests, azure-devops-rest-api

I was trying to automate the task of pushing some files to various folder in a repo. I tried using Rest API provided by azure. When using Pushes Create API for the same, from the docs this is the content in the request body

Snapshot of request body:

[image]

This is the specific thing i can't figure out how to get in python script
"oldObjectId": "8b67126d2500e28c771f82c9ddc292679978197c"

I know I have to send a JSON variable containing the data similar to above using python requests library. But I don't know how to get the oldobjectid in the python script. I tried looking everywhere(documentation,stackoverflow....) but can't see to find how we can find the oldobjectid.

The link for the documentation of the [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How to find oldobjectid when Uploading/pushing a file to Azure Devops Repo using Pushes Create Api with Python

The `oldobjectid` is the **latest commit ID** on the current branch for the Azure Devops Repo.

To get the `oldObjectId` (latest commit id), we could use the REST API [Pushes - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) with URI Parameters `top=1` and `searchCriteria.refName=refs/heads/master`:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?&$top=1&searchCriteria.refName=refs/heads/master&api-version=6.0
```

[image]

Now, we get the `pushId`, and we could use the REST API [Pushes - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the `commitId`:

[image]

Then, we could use the REST API Pushes - Create with request body:

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "e71544e80870e83cfd3eb3a797eda9c6227c66a7"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Added task markdown file.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "add",
          "item": {
            "path": "/tasks.md"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "# Tasks\n\n* Item 1\n* Item 2",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for giving us direction, I've been running around in circles looking for the meaning of this