# (Azure DevOps, git) How to edit a file via REST API without cloning the repository?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps (online), I can simply click "edit" button to edit a file and commit:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfv2U.png)

How do I perform click edit button via REST API?

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I'm sorry but it would be some time before I try your solution. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> (Azure DevOps, git) How to edit a file via REST API without cloning the repository?

There is no such REST API to edit the file like perform click edit button.

That is because the `Edit` button just changes the state of the file to an editable state, there's no REST request in essence until you're done changing the file and committing the file.

You can verify this with developer tools `F12`, when you click the edit button, no request is sent：

[image]

So there is no way to do this through REST API, we can only change files through REST API [Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/Pushes/Create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#update_a_file):

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=5.0
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. All I want is to update a file using API. Do you mean that all I need is to post with an `edit` change to this url? In that case, how do I get `oldObjectId`?

Comment: @BrandonStudio, To do this, please check my previous answer, it provide detailes info and steps:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014038/how-to-find-oldobjectid-when-uploading-pushing-a-file-to-azure-devops-repo-using/66023373#66023373

Comment: Can I have an once-for-all authentication method to list and push repositories?